# AX 2009 AIF Schema error: SalesOrder:AxdEnum_Timezone' is not declared, or is not a simple type

Tags: schema, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I've been changing the SalesOrderService document service. Initially I'd added the new datasource at the wrong level, deployed the service, and later corrected it. The new datasource I've added is Address and now it hangs off of CreditCardCust datasource.

I've updated the document service using the wizard (checked the boxes for regenerating the document and AxBC class) and deployed the service again.

When I try to test the service using the XML file adapter, I get the following error: Type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder:AxdEnum_Timezone' is not declared, or is not a simple type.

I can reproduce the error by navigating to EndPoints, selecting the sales order inbound endpoint, Action policies, Parameter schema, View schema. Clearly, the schema is messed up.

I tried to regenerate the schema using the GenerateXSDSchema_AxdSalesOrder to no avail.

Is there a way for me to clear the schema and regenerate again?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to add more detail about the changes you made to the document service, e.g. which tables did you add to the query and if they are custom tables, what is their structure? I suspect at least one field of the tables has a `UTCDateTime` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the Address datasource on the query and updated the service. That got rid of the problem and restored the service to a good state.

Looking through the list of available services, I found DirAddress service. That indicates to me that I cannot add address directly in SalesOrder service, but have to make a separate call to add the address.